# objects inserted into containers must be cleared at the destructor?

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, containers

Suppose:

```
struct Foo
{
    int _b;
    std::string _name;
};

class Bar
{
public:
    vector<Foo>hold;
};
```

If a call to `hold.clear()` isn't done on the destructor, does it means a memory leak?
I'm talking about objects, not pointer, because as far as I know `push_back` creates a copy of the original object;

Comment: Small note: *Destructor.

Comment: I'm starting to think you are a S.O bot @chris, do you ever sleep?

Comment: Eventually. Moreso when I have school in the morning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When an object is destroyed, so is all its members. So the (automatically generated) destructor of Bar will call the destructor of its hold member, which is going to call the destructors of its elements.

In summary: everything is destroyed automatically. This is a guarantee in C++: if you are manipulating objects by value, you have the guarantee that they are going to be destroyed when they get out of scope. The only thing you have to destroy explicitly are the objects that have been allocated on the heap (i.e. using new).

Comment: I see because, `hold` is destroyed, so is all of its members

Comment: yes, this is a property of all properly designed containers (the standard containers being properly designed)

Answer (score 1):

No, there are no memory leaks. When a `Bar` goes out of scope, it's data member `hold` is destroyed, and because `std::vector` is well designed, all the elements it holds are destroyed.

```
struct Foo
{
    int _b;
    std::string _name;
    ~Foo() { std::cout << "Foo destructor"; }
};

class Bar
{
public:
    vector<Foo>hold;
};

int main()

{

  {
    Bar b;
    b.hold.push_back(Foo());
  } // Foo, vector<Foo> and b instances destroyed here

}
```